# C# Foreach XML node

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I'm trying to add all the nodes in an XML file into a listView, and I'm doing something wrong but I can't for the life of me figure it out even after looking at a load of examples. This is the XML snippet:

```
<queue>
<slots>
<slot>
<status>Downloading</status>
<filename>file1</filename>
<size>1 GB</size>
</slot>
<slot>
<status>Downloading</status>
<filename>file2</filename>
<size>2 GB</size>
</slot>
</slots>
</queue>
```

And here's the code:

```
        XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(xmlFilePath);

        List<Download> list = new List<Download>();

        foreach (var download in xDoc.Descendants("slots"))
        {
            string filename = download.Element("filename").Value;
            string size = download.Element("size").Value;
            string status = download.Element("status").Value;
            list.Add(new Download { Filename = filename, Size = size, Status = status });              
        }
```

Any help greatly appreciated as always.

EDIT: To clarify, I'm getting a NullReferenceException on

```
string filename = download.Element("filename").Value;
```

And i know the listview is missing, I've not done that bit yet :)

Comment: Are you using WPF or Winforms? I see you creating a list. How is the list bound to the listview?

And what's not working?  Are you getting an exception?  Is the list just not filling?  Is there nothing in the listview?  Is there nothing in Decendents?

Comment: Sorry I've made it a little more clear now!

Comment: Try xDoc.Descandants("slots") instead

Comment: Sorry Oskar, "slots" is the one that causes the Null error, "slot" just returns the first download

Comment: "slot" is correct, see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var list = (from download in xDoc.Descendats("slot")
            select new Download
                    {
                        Filename = (string) download.Element("filename"),
                        Size = (string) download.Element("size"),
                        Status = (string) download.Element("status")
                    }).ToList();
```

This looks nicer, and since you didn't say what exactly is wrong with your code, it's about all I can do.

Update: just tested this, and it fixes your exception.

Comment: Spot on, and it does look nicer too!

Comment: This fixes the NullReferenceException by ignoring the possibly malformed XML and inserting a null for the filename.

Comment: @Yuriy The `NullReferenceException` was caused by trying to access `filename` node as an element of `slots` node, instead of an element of `slot` node. You can take care missing values later (e.g. `.Where(d => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(d.Filename))`).

Comment: Sure if he changed it, but originally he had `slot`.

Answer (score 2):

The XML in your example works fine. The NullReferenceException is happening because the real XML you're using doesn't have a filename element in one of the slots. You can use

```
string filename = download.Element("filename") == null ? 
    String.Empty : download.Element("filename").Value;
```

instead if there is a possible default for the `filename`. But more likely correctly handling this exception is better.

Answer (score 1):

```
void LoadSlots()
{
  XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
  doc.Load(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\queue.xml");

  XmlNodeList nodes = doc.SelectNodes("//queue/slots/slot");

  foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
  {
    string filename = node.Attributes["filename"].InnerText;
    string size = node.Attributes["size"].InnerText;
    string status = node.Attributes["status"].InnerText;
    _slots.Add(filename, size, status);
  }
}
```

Comment: Why did you change it to use XmlDocument instead of XDocument? Then you have filename, size and status as attributes instead of elements as originally posted. And then there is a cryptic _slots, what is it?

Comment: Sorry, I ran it and it works though.  Replace `_slots` with `list`.  I just gave it a specific name, i.e. `private List<QueueSlot> _slots = new List<QueueSlot>();`

Comment: Another typo though, should be, `_slots.Add(new QueueSlot(filename, size, status);`

Comment: I did it the old fashioned way!  It's probably inefficient or something though.